# Global param on multiple webresources

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I am building a webservices application using jersey,jax-rs

I have single jax-rs resource file at path "/authenticate"

I have multiple methods with individual paths like "/user" "/test"

```
@Path ("/authenticate")
public class Authenticate{
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Authenticate.class);

@QueryParam("entityId")
String entity;

@GET
@Path ("/{param}")
public Response getMsg(@PathParam ("param") String msg) {
    String o = "Hello Welcome Back:"+msg;
    return Response.status(200).entity(o).build();
}

@GET
@Path ("/user")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public UserDTO getUser (@Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @QueryParam("userId") int userId) {
    System.out.println("In Get User, User:"+userId);    
    System.out.println("In Get User, Entity:"+entity);
}

@GET
@Path ("/test")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public TestPOJO getTestPOJO () {
    System.out.println("In Get TestPOJO");
    System.out.println("In Get Test, Entity:"+entity);
    return new TestPOJO();
}
```

}

As suggested for jersey client, I am using a single webresource from client and build subsequent webresources from the same webresource by using .path("/xxx").

Here is how I create the initial web resource

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/Service/jaxrs/authenticate");
webResource.queryParam("entityId", securityHelper.getEntityId().toString());
```

Here is how I use the webresource subsequently

```
MultivaluedMap<String, String> params = new MultivaluedMapImpl();           
ClientResponse userRes = webResource.path("/user").queryParams(params).accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

I want to assign a queryparam to the initial webresource, and I want that to be retained by all subsequent webresources created using the .path(). But that is not happening right now. For example in the above code "entityId" is not available when the call with path("/user") is made.

My idea is to assign common parameters once and all subsequent users of the webResource need not add those again and again. Is there a way to do it? Will this approach work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below creates a new WebResource and not changing the state of the webResource object:

```
webResource.queryParam("entityId", securityHelper.getEntityId().toString())
```

Eventually you could change your code like this to create the "base" resource:

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/Service/jaxrs/authenticate").queryParam("entityId", securityHelper.getEntityId().toString());
```

And then use this resource to create another resources as you like. WebResource.queryParam and WebResource.queryParams always create a new WebResource object.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was off for few days and just saw this. So if I understand it, if I use queryParam when creating the webResource, it will stay with it. I will try.

Comment: mind that queryParam creates a new webresource, so you should use that one and not the one on which you call queryParam.

Answer (score 0):

I'm may not be the best person to answer this since I have entered the "world" of Jersey and RESTful servers not too long ago but since i saw this unanswered for 2 days ill try to help out as best as I can.

If i understood correctly you are trying to, by using a query, save the user information on entityId String so it will be available when you make a subsequent call.

Ok let's start with what you have. With your code (entityId as a global parameter), what you are specifying , is that when you are calling a resource from the Authenticate class, any call can be made with a query of the type '?entityId="something" and ANY method in this class can use the information sent in the query.

The thing is, for what I've learned by messing about with Jersey, whenever you make a call, the resource class (in your case Authenticate) is instantiated again. Therefor you can't just keep information in a global parameter since subsequent calls will have the String entityId as null.

This means that if you want to save the information you'll have to do it in a external resource (ex: db, file, etc). What method you choose depends on what you want to do and what are you looking for in your application.

I hope I was at least able to shed a sliver of light on your problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Your understanding is correct to any extent. I am trying to access a web resource that requires a identification of the requester. So instead of trying to add that everywhere in the code where the webresource is used, i am trying to set that once so that that parameter is add to all the webresource requests.